# Is there any way to implement rich text box in angular 2?

Tags: angular, richtextbox

I am working on angular 2 project in which i need to use Rich Text Box. How can i implement it in angular 2? all i found [textangular](http://textangular.com/). but seems like this will not work in angular 2.

Comment: Rich textbox? You mean you want something like markdown? Or are you actually talking about something like RTF?

Comment: @DylanMeeus actually kind of. Thing is i want Gmail like Rich Text Box.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**! You can add anything you want that uses **javascript** to your Angular application. In my case I use **Tinymce** and **WysiBB** just adding the **js** in index and definition files (**d.ts**) in compiler **lifecycle**.

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented Tinymce. Now looking for getting its values,

Comment: @ReginaldoCamargoRibeiro `Tinymce` is it free?

Comment: @levi Sorry, it used to be free, but not anymore.